# How to split a Maven multi-module build into multiple Jenkins build jobs?

Tags: maven, jenkins

Let's consider a multi-module project which is composed of modules A, B, C, D, E. The dependencies among these are

- C depends on B; B depends A
- E depends on D; D depends B

I'd like to split this into two Jenkins builds

- Build 1: Build C and its dependencies i.e. `-pl :C -am`
- Copy Jenkins workspace
- Build 2: Build E, D by utilizing the B.jar built by Build 1

I'm unable to figure out a way to tell Maven to do "Build 2". This is a simplified scenario but in my case there are several modules instead of just 5.

Comment: If you have a correctly configured multi module build you can simply call `mvn clean deploy ` on the root level of your project structure. If you like to call child modules in your Jenkins jobs that sounds like there is a problem in your build...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the -pl option to target a specific module.  http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html.

Generally I don't see this done, though - if a project is multi-module, usually folks just invoke maven from the CI on the parent and let maven be responsible for building everything, as opposed to duplicating in the CI tool knowledge about dependencies/sub-components internal to the project that is already defined to maven.  If there's a problem with a particular module building, Jenkins will still expose that in build log.

Comment: Thanks. The `-pl` and `-am` will help with "Build 1". But I'm not sure how to model "Build 2" with those reactor options.